# Use separate subs without invoking proporties

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety, invoke

I am trying to achieve a linear code without any "background workers" running alongside my main program (with the exception of a few System.Windows.Forms.Timers).  I'm using Private Subs in order to eliminate the need to copy and paste, for example, the same 50 lines of code 10 times in my program (making it easier to edit and skim through).  However, I ran into the problem of cross threading.  As I understand it because I am not accessing a property from the UI thread, the code:

```
Private Sub Update()
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
            ...
            ...
            ...
End Sub
```

Gives me the error:

> Control 'DataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Until now I've been using `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` in my form_load event but now I'm running into some issues with timers not restarting.

Is there a way can get it to run linearly so I don't have to invoke the method every time?  I've got about 2000 lines of code right now and I'd hate to have to go through and invoke every instance of `Button50.enabled = true` and so on.

Comment: Invoking/Delegating is the right way to access controls from worker threads. You do need to go back and fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.Net Framework 4.0` we have been able to use a Lambda sub for delegating. You can even call methods inside this `Sub`.

Example:

```
Private Sub Update()
  Me.Invoke(Sub()
              'update controls or form in here - thread safe
            End Sub)
```

Comment: Thanks! A note to anyone trying the same thing though: you need a "()" after the first "Sub".  So use: "Me.Invoke(Sub()".